# Redmine email notifications

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I am starting to work with redmine and I need to configure the email notifications for users
I want users to receive emails when there is an issue assigned to a group they are part of,but I also want some specific users (like managers) to receive all emails from all issues.
And the actual configuration of redmine does not allow me to do that because is the same configuration for all users.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

That kind of configuration is user specific. The admin can set up the default level of notification in Administration -> Settings -> Notifications, but every user can set up a custom level in "My account".

You could, however, bulk-modify the notification setting for specific users using a database script. The notification setting appears to be in the "mail_notification" field of the "users table".

For instance, in my Redmine instance I've got the several values:

```
select distinct(mail_notification) from users;

only_my_events
only_assigned
selected
none
```

After I set up my own configuration to "For all events on all my projects", as you want, a new value 'all' appears.

Therefore, you might try a script like:

```
update users
set mail_notification='all'
where id in ('user1_id','user2_id',......'usern_id');
```

It's dirty, and I would try it first in a test environment (and backup your production database before doing it in production), but it will probably work.

Bear in mind that, even if you set up the notification configuration for a user this way, (s)he can log in later and set it up to another value. There is no way to block users from changing that parameter as far as I know.